# How to get if an element is in view?

Tags: javascript

In my application I want to use:

```
element.scrollIntoView()
```

To make sure the element is inside the viewport, it works.

However, I found that it may cause some problem, for example when an element is inside the viewport and then I set it 'into view'. Then the scroll bar will move accordingly, this is not what I expected.

So, I want to make sure the element is not inside the viewport, then call the `scrollIntoView`.

How to get if the element is inside the viewport or not?

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the Viewport plugin for jQuery and it's worked great.

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport

With this plugin, you can do something like:

```
if($(".something:in-viewport").length) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This function checks if an element is entirely in the viewport.

```
function isElementCompletelyInViewPort(element) {

    var elementData = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
        width = document.documentElement.clientWidth,
        height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    return ( 
            elementData.bottom <= height
            && elementData.right <= width
            && elementData.left >= 0
            && elementData.top >= 0);       
}
```

getBoundingClientRect is lesser known, but supported by all major browsers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getBoundingClientRect

Any improvement suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: It just test whether the elemnt is inside the document while I want test whether an elemet is inside another element.